# How can i add new layers to an OlMap after constructing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-3

I build a map inside the `constructor` my class, something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.mapDivId = `map-${Math.random()}`;

    const baseLayer = new OlLayerTile({
        name: 'OSM',
        source: new OlSourceOSM()
    })

    this.map = new OlMap({
        //Assign Layers
        layers: [        
            baseLayer,            
        ],    
        view: new OlView({        
            center: fromLonLat(VIEW_CENTER),
            zoom: ZOOM,
        })
    });
}
```

Now everything works great, i can add any layer i want when i'm in the constructor, now here is the problem, i want to pass new layers through the props of my class (when some api is called) something like this:

```
<Map layers={layers}/>
```

And i want these layers to be assigned to the map! but no matter what i do, i fail, here is a couple of things i tried:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (!JavascriptUtils.isArrayEquel(prevState.layers, this.props.layers)) {
            //solution 1: 
            (this.props.layers || []).forEach(layer => {
                this.map.addLayer(layer)
            })
            //solution 2:
            // this.map.layers = [
            //     this.state.baseLayer,
            //     ...(this.props.layers || [])
            // ]

            this.setState({ layers: this.props.layers })
        }
    }
```

How can i handle adding new layers to my map ?, **i simply want the map's layer to change whenever the layer props changes**

Comment: Did you try to render the map after calling the addLayer ?

Comment: @A. Roussos, i'm a complete beginner in openlayer, how can i rerender the map again ?, currently i tried another solution in which i give a new `key` to my component and force the dom to render a whole new component this means the constructor is force to run again and i get the result i want, but i'm not sure if this is best thing to do or not.

Comment: try map.render()

Comment: `map.addLayer(layer)` should work fine .. can you add more information about the layers an how are you setting the prop? .. BTW, you should remove the layers before adding, if not you are reflecting the change of the prop you are accumulating the layers